# MySQL Update & Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table containing contact details, and I need to flag duplicates of the column "PHONE1" into another flag column called "DUPLICATE" (ignoring the first, original, row).

I found an SQL tutorial with an example SQL query doing almost exactly what I want here: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-update-join/.

I modified the tutorial example, and I can "SELECT" the duplicate rows correctly with the following query:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.`Contact Name`, t1.PHONE1
FROM new_leads_test2 AS t1
INNER JOIN new_leads_test2 AS t2
ON (t1.PHONE1 = t2.PHONE1
AND t1.ID > t2.ID)
```

this "SELECT" query works 100%, but when I try to alter this query to actually UPDATE the rows (per the tutorial), I get an SQL syntax error. Here's my query that generates the error:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.duplicate = t2.ID
FROM new_leads_test2 AS t1
INNER JOIN new_leads_test2 AS t2
ON (t1.PHONE1 = t2.PHONE1
AND t1.ID > t2.ID)
```

This results in an SQL error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'FROM new_leads_test2 AS t1
>  INNER JOIN new_leads_test2 AS
> t2
>  ON t1.PHONE1 = t2.' at line 3

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @PaulT. - edited to include the exact error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We might put `SET` after `INNER JOIN` because [UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html), `table_reference` use before `SET`

BTW maybe you might not need `FROM`

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
SET assignment_list
[WHERE where_condition]
[ORDER BY ...]
[LIMIT row_count]
```

so we might use like below.

```
UPDATE new_leads_test2 AS t1
INNER JOIN new_leads_test2 AS t2
ON (t1.PHONE1 = t2.PHONE1
AND t1.ID > t2.ID)
SET t1.duplicate = t2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a SQL Server syntax, not MySQL.

Try with:

```
UPDATE new_leads_test2 t1
 INNER JOIN new_leads_test2 t2
    ON (t1.PHONE1 = t2.PHONE1 AND t1.ID > t2.ID)
   SET t1.duplicate = t2.ID
```

Comment: Thanks Paul - this query worked with no errors, although it also set the original row's "DUPLICATE" column to zero, instead of leaving it as null. Very helpful though!